# Certificate issuer key size error?

Tags: visual-studio, certificate, key, size, makecert

I want to create an certificate, and i have this error:
How i can change the Issuer key size?
[image]

Code:

```html
makecert.exe ^
-n "CN=MyName"^
-r ^
-pe ^
-a sha512 ^
-$ individual ^
-len 4096 ^
-cy authority ^
-sv MyName.pvk ^
MyName.cer

pvk2pfx.exe ^
-pvk MyName.pvk ^
-spc MyName.cer ^
-pfx MyName.pfx ^
-po test
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a misleading error, which appears to be thrown when Makecert.exe tries to generate a certificate using an invalid authority (in my case the authority I had created didn't have a password on it's private key)

Remove your existing self-signed Certificate Authority (if you already created one) then follow the instructions here:

http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/38/using-makecert-to-create-certificates-for-development